# Update Passed Data from Parent to Child After Axios Request React

Tags: reactjs, axios

From the title itself. I am fairly new to react and would like to know
how would you update the already "passed" data from parent to child. I have an alert component that will display the error message depending on the data acquired after an Axios request.

Parent
..

```
    this.state = { 
                formContact: { 
                    fullname: '',
                    contact:'',
                    email: '',
                    message: ''
                },
                formAlert: { alertMessage: 'default'}
            };

     handleClick() {

            let rm = this;
            axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'submit',
                data: {
                    form: this.state.formContact
                    }
                })
                .then(function (response) {
                    let data = response.data.data;
                    rm.setState({ 
                        formAlert: { alertMessage: 'test' }
                    });

                }).catch(function (response) {
                    //handle error
                    console.log(response);
                });
        }

  render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
               <Alert data={this.state.formAlert}  />
            </div>
       );
    }
}
```

Child

```
class Alert extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(props);

        // Holds the form state and input boxes
        this.state = { 
            formError: { 
                icon: '',
                header: '',
                message: '',
                errorType: 'errormsg'
            }
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={'style-msg ' + this.state.formError.errorType}>
                <div className="sb-msg"><i className="icon-thumbs-up"></i>
                    <strong>Well done!</strong>
                    {this.state.formError.message}
                </div>
                <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

It seems I cannot update the formAlert.alertMessage to "test" and pass the new data "test" to the child.

Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have passed data to `Alert` component,

```
<Alert data={this.state.formAlert}  />
```

But in `Alert` component, you have never used that data.

I think instead of this,

```
{this.state.formError.message}
```

you should use this,

```
{this.props.data.alertMessage}
```

**Update**

In order to set `props` to `state` do this,

```
formError: { 
   icon: '',
   header: '',
   message: props.data.alertMessage,
   errorType: 'errormsg'
}
```

Now you can use,

```
{this.state.formError.message}
```

When data changes after first render your `Alert` component's state will not get new data, for this you need `componentDidUpdate` method,

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevProps.data.alertMessage !== this.props.data.alertMessage) {
    let formError = {...this.state.formError};
    formError.message = this.props.data.alertMessage
    this.setState({formError},()=>console.log(this.state.formError.message))
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes it works. However, I want the props.data.alertMessage to be set on t he Child's this.state.formError. message and then render the updated object @ravibagul91

Comment: Tried it. But the state.formError.message is still using the same value and not from the axios result that I was hoping for. @ravibagul91

Comment: it's better to use the props when the parent data is updated after that component rerender again and no need to use state

Comment: @ravibagul91 Thank you it really worked. But i also somehow manage to have my solution. Just a question though I used this this.alert = React.createRef();

and created a function inside Alert.js named update(data) in which data stores the newly updated data being accepted inside the axios. Is my solution also correct? or using the componentDidUpdate the proper way? Thank you

Comment: Yes. `ref` can be used to trigger function from child component, but only for `class based component` and not for `functional component`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Child Component` should use the data props to show the alert.

```
    class Alert extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(props);

        // Holds the form state and input boxes
        this.state = { 
            formError: { 
                icon: '',
                header: '',
                message: '',
                errorType: 'errormsg'
            }
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={'style-msg ' + this.state.formError.errorType}>
                <div className="sb-msg"><i className="icon-thumbs-up"></i>
                    <strong>Well done!</strong>
                    {this.props.data.alertMessage}
                </div>
                <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```